# I m unable to execute a program using jxl

Tags: java

Source fie ->
location c:/program files/java/jdk1.6.0_07/bin

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.*;
public class Geeta {

 private String inputFile;

 public void setInputFile(String inputFile) {
  this.inputFile = inputFile;
 }

 public void read() throws Exception  {

  File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);

   Workbook w;
  w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
   // Get the first sheet
   Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
   // Loop over first 10 column and lines
   Cell a1 = sheet.getCell(0,0);


String stringa1 = a1.getContents();
   System.out.println(stringa1);


 }


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Geeta test = new Geeta();

test.setInputFile("c:/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.6.0_07/bin/jxlrwtest.xls");
  test.read();
 }

}
```

compiled as 
javac -classpath jxl.jar Geeta.java

When I try to execute it says.. NoClassDefFoundError

java -jar jxl.jar Geeta

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\bin>java -jar jxl.jar Geeta
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Geeta
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Geeta
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)

Plz. advice...

Answer (score 1):

I had an error with jxl execution, it was about the CLASSPATH

This works to me:

1. Change or set the CLASSPATH in Environment Variables:

   - Open Explorer (Windows-E)
   - Right-click on Computer
   - Select Properties
   - On the "Advanced" Tab select "Environment Variables..."
   - On System variables window, Edit or Add a new variable named: CLASSPATH
   - On Variable Value set the place where jxl.jar is, example: .;C:\YourPath\jxl.jar
2. Open a new CMD window and compile as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Your run command should look like this:

```
java -classpath jxl.jar;. Geeta
```